# Camera+ Clarity Filter and GPUImage

Tags: image-processing, instagram, gpuimage, clarity

I'm playing around with doing some camera filters using GPUImage and attempting get get something resembling Camera+'s Clarity filter (not expecting to match 100% of course, but to get in the same ballpark). But I can not seem to get anywhere close to the effect. Any idea what Clarity is doing from a conceptual standpoint?

Comment: This is the same or similar to the Lux effect in Instagram, correct?

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29503/how-to-i-get-the-instagram-lux-effect-without-using-instagram) contains a good conceptual discussion about the Lux effect in Instagram, which is similar to the Clarity effect in Camera+ (if I'm not mistaken).